# Controlling rdp listener connections from command line

Tags: windows-server-2003, command-line-interface, scripting, rdp

RPD on my windows 2003 server sometimes becomes incapable to accept connections. But netstat shows that port is listened.

```
c:\> netstat -ano | find "3389"
TCP    192.168.1.1:3389     0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING     3224
```

nmap from linux machine shows than port is closed.
I have tried some recipes and have lost hope =(

so: i can execute tscc.msc and restart listener! can i do that from command line (to write script)?

Comment: Why not just stop and restart the Terminal Services service?

Comment: `net stop _servicename_` does not work. @joeqwerty, does windows really not have a mechanism of controlling rdp listeners via command line? When I started to search, I thought that will be very simple

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error message? Are you running: net stop "Terminal Services" with the quotes?

Comment: It seems, the problem is solved by re-creation of the listener. if problem will appear again, i'll add error message of command 'net stop'

Comment: When I'm entering `net stop "Terminal Services"`, it says:

`The requested pause or stop is not valid for this service.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2191`